# Uncommon usage of form attributes in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm writing a simple CMS, where on each page users can edit all its attached languages. For example, the raw `$_POST` input when a user submits a form, typically must look like as following:

```
array(
   'fr' => array(
      'name' => 'Some name in French',
      'content' => 'Some content in French'
   ),
   'en' => array(
      'name' => 'Some name in English',
      'content' => 'Some content in English'
   ),
   'de' => array(
      'name' => 'Some name in German',
      'content' => 'Some content in German'
   )
)
```

I have no problem managing simple inputs, that look like as typical a `key => value` pair. However I can't get this to work, and I've spent several hours searching for similar issues with no luck, so here are my questions:

- How to define that in module's form?
- How to attach validation rules accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in ZF2 for this is very simple.

Just create a Fieldset for each type with their name (de/en/fr) and in each fieldset define the fields (name/content) and the validation itself.

Then combine the 3 fieldset in a form and display it in the view.

The submitted POST data will be automtically grouped inside the name of the fieldsets.

http://www.aronkerr.com/2013/11/zf2-form-collection-validation-unique.html